# Changing a pretrained Keras model with fixed input to a flexible one in tensoflow?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, keras-layer

I want to use a pre-trained BagNet (https://github.com/wielandbrendel/bag-of-local-features-models) to extract features. The net has fixed input height and width, the input is `(None,3,224,224)`. Now, I want to build a new model with fexible input sizes. I tried approaches with model.layers.pop()[0] to remove the first layer and replace it with a flexible input but I get errors:

> ValueError: Graph disconnected: cannot obtain value for tensor Tensor("input0_6:0", shape=(?, 3, 224, 224), dtype=float32) at layer "input0". The following previous layers were accessed without issue: []

```
keras_model = bagnets.keras.bagnet8()
keras_model.layers.pop()[0]
x = Input(batch_shape=(None, 3, None, None))   
newModel = Model(x, keras_model.output)
```

How could I ressolve this issue or what are other options?